# Is it OK to use bitfields in dynamically allocated structure in C?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, malloc, bit-fields

I'm going to implement a singly linked list program with bitfield in its structure, something like this:

```
typedef struct large
{
    unsigned number :4;
    struct large *next;
} large;

int main()
{
    large *g;
    g=(large *)malloc(sizeof(large));

    g->number=15;
    printf("%d",g->number);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The above program is **working correctly** but I read in *GeeksForGeeks* that,

> We cannot have pointers to bit field members as they may not start at
>   a byte boundary.

Will there be problems if I code it further for linked list implementation?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You don't have any pointers to bitfield members.

Comment: You are aware this will not save you anything, are you? And why do you want to use bitfields at all? They only make sense to safe memory, are you on a heavily memory-limited platform?

Comment: In C you do not need to typecast return result from malloc

Comment: You can use `g->number` without problem; you're not using the address of a bit-field but of a structure containing a bit-field.  What you can't do is `&g->number` — that is verboten because the bit-field isn't necessarily aligned with a byte boundary, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer `g` in your program is a pointer to a structure variable to which you allocated memory dynamically.

`g->number` is not the address of the member `number` but its value.

You cannot have a pointer like

```
unsigned char *ptr=&(g->number);
```

you should get an error like `cannot take address of bit-field`

Answer (score 0):

malloc-ing any structures including those containing bitfields is absolutely OK

> ```
> We cannot have pointers to bit field members as they may not start at a byte boundary.
> ```

But you do not get the address of the bitfield - only for the structure itself and its size and location is always a multiple of byte.